# Form input is not clickable on an inline form

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, webkit

With the latest update of Chrome to revision 19.0.1084.52 we notice some strange behavior on forms on our website.

When the form has a style with display:inline and position:relative and the input is wrapped
in a div that floats then the input is not selectable anymore

Here is the most simple example of the bug (check it in Chrome)

```html
<form action="" method="get" style="display:inline; position:relative">
  <div>
    <label>test1</label>
    <input id="test1" name="test1" type="text" value="clickable" />
  </div>
  <div style="float: left;">
    <label>test2</label>
    <input id="test2" name="test2" type="text" value="not clickable" />
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"><input type="submit" value="submit"></div>
</form>
```

Is this a browser bug or is this style not possible?

Comment: Set the form to `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Hey replace `float:left` into `inline-block`

As like this

```html
<form action="" method="get" style="display:inline; position:relative">
  <div>
    <label>test1</label>
    <input id="test1" name="test1" type="text" value="clickable" />
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <label>test2</label>
    <input id="test2" name="test2" type="text" value="not clickable" />
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"><input type="submit" value="submit"></div>
</form>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/t4a3r/
​

Comment: Yes, thanks, but fixing it is not realy the issue, it's just strange that an update of chrome causes this strange behavior on previously fine html.